# Difference 2 arrays into a totals array

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have 2 JavaScript multi-dimensional array of fruits.

```
Array 1
-------------
Item, Count
Apple, 1
Apple, 1
Apple, 1
Orange, 1
Orange, 1
Orange, 1

Array 2
--------------
Item, Count
Apple, 1
Orange, 1
```

I'd like a new array where items in Array 2 are removed from Array 1 and added together.

```
Array Result
--------------
Item, Total
Apple, 2
Orange, 2
```

Comment: Cool, please keep us informed!

Comment: Can you provide the JavaScript array structure, it is unclear from your questions

Comment: @Rod could you please show those Arrays in Javascript, like:
`[ ['Apple', 1], ['Apple', 1] /* (...) */ ]`, because I'm not sure what you mean with 'multi-dimensional' array, since the only way to have them in Javascript is by having an array of arrays. There is no native multiple-dimensional arrays in Javascript.

Comment: Wouldn't two nested for loops solve it? The outer one looping through the first array, and the inner checking the element's existence in the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var Array1 = [{Apple: 1},{Apple: 1},{Apple: 1},{Orange: 1},{Orange: 1},{Orange: 1}];
var Array2 = [{Apple: 1},{Orange: 1}];

var Result = Array2.reduce(function(res, item) {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(res, key) {
        res[key] = res[key] || 0;
        res[key] -= parseInt(item[key]);
        return res
    }, res);
}, Array1.reduce(function(res, item) {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(res, key) {
        res[key] = res[key] || 0;
        res[key] += parseInt(item[key]);
        return res
    }, res);
}, {}));

var Answer = Object.keys(Result).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    var o = {};
    o[key] = Result[key];
    return arr.push(o) && arr;
}, []);

console.log(Answer);
```

Alternatively, if the input data is in the following format

```js
var Array1 = [['Apple', 1],['Apple', 1],['Apple', 1],['Orange', 1],['Orange', 1],['Orange', 1]];
var Array2 = [['Apple', 1],['Orange', 1]];

var Result = Array2.reduce(function(res, item) {
    var key = item[0], value = item[1];
    res[key] = res[key] || 0;
    res[key] -= parseInt(value);
    return res;
}, Array1.reduce(function(res, item) {
    var key = item[0], value = item[1];
    res[key] = res[key] || 0;
    res[key] += parseInt(value);
    return res;
}, {}));

var Answer = Object.keys(Result).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    return arr.push([key, Result[key]]) && arr;
}, []);

console.log(Answer);
```